# How to set two timers both on cpu time and real time of a process?

Tags: c, linux, unix, timer, setitimer

I try to use `setitimer(ITIMER_PROF, &tick, NULL)` to limit the cpu time consuming by the process. But if the process turns to suspend (in my case ,the process sinks into a dead loop, then the Ubuntu16.04 suspends it and does not wake up it again), the timer cannot kill the process.

If I use:

```
setitimer(ITIMER_PROF, &tick1, NULL);
setitimer(ITIMER_REAL, &tick2, NULL);
```

to limit a bigger real time. The man page said the later `setitimer` will overwrite the former.

How can I use `setitimer` to limit the process time, both on cpu time and real time ?

Comment: Where in the man page does it say that?

Comment: *`setitimer()` will overwrite the former* <= that would be weird, since one delivers `SIGPROF` and the other `SIGALRM`. The disabling part is relative to the timer (i.e. the `which`) argument. So unless something's seriously broken behind the scenes, your code should work as expected.

Comment: @dhke Yes, you are right. Thanks ! I mistook the case of 2 calls of `setitimer` using the same `which`.

Comment: Side note: (this happened to me, because I'm stupid): of course, ITIMER_PROF only increments when the process is actually doing any work. You --of course-- need to perform actual calculation.